# how can we forward the incoming SNMP trap to other IP address in java

Tags: java, nms

I am new in development, I got the SNMP Trap in the form PDU in java file and I want to forward the incoming trap to other Ip address.

can anyone help me to forward SNMP-Trap to other host

Comment: What library are you using? SNMP4J? Do you need to supply trap IP origin information?

Comment: yes, I m using SNMP4J, I just want, I got the trap from the source Ip, like  192.168.174 .30 and I want to delver this trap to other host 192.168.174.58